# Find value of input field in html doc using python

Tags: python

I am trying to get input values from an HTML doc and want to parse out the values of hidden input fields. For example how can I parse out only the value from the snippet below, using python.

```
    <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="post_form_id" name="post_form_id" value="d619a1eb3becdc05a3ebea530396782f" />
    <input type="hidden" name="fb_dtsg" value="AQCYsohu" autocomplete="off" />
```

And the output of the python function should return something like:

```
post_form_id : d619a1eb3becdc05a3ebea530396782f
fb_dtsg : AQCYsohu
```

Comment: Check this beautiful answer here -http://stackoverflow.com/a/11205758/609782

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
>>> htmlstr = """    <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="post_form_id" name="post_form_id" value="d619a1eb3becdc05a3ebea530396782f" />
...     <input type="hidden" name="fb_dtsg" value="AQCYsohu" autocomplete="off" />"""
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlstr)
>>> [(n['name'], n['value']) for n in soup.findAll('input')]
[(u'post_form_id', u'd619a1eb3becdc05a3ebea530396782f'), (u'fb_dtsg', u'AQCYsohu')]
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting BeautifulSoup, this is even better than what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Or with [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/):

```
import lxml.html

htmlstr = '''
    <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="post_form_id" name="post_form_id" value="d619a1eb3becdc05a3ebea530396782f" />
    <input type="hidden" name="fb_dtsg" value="AQCYsohu" autocomplete="off" />
'''

// Parse the string and turn it into a tree of elements
htmltree = lxml.html.fromstring(htmlstr)

// Iterate over each input element in the tree and print the relevant attributes
for input_el in htmltree.xpath('//input'):
    name = input_el.attrib['name']
    value = input_el.attrib['value']

    print "%s : %s" % (name, value)
```

**Gives:**

```
post_form_id : d619a1eb3becdc05a3ebea530396782f
fb_dtsg : AQCYsohu
```