# Get an attribute value based on the name attribute with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to print an attribute value based on its name, take for example

```
<META NAME="City" content="Austin">
```

I want to do something like this

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(f)  # f is some HTML containing the above meta tag
for meta_tag in soup("meta"):
    if meta_tag["name"] == "City":
        print(meta_tag["content"])
```

The above code give a `KeyError: 'name'`, I believe this is because name is used by BeatifulSoup so it can't be used as a keyword argument.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

It's pretty simple, use the following:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<META NAME="City" content="Austin">')
>>> soup.find("meta", {"name":"City"})
<meta name="City" content="Austin" />
>>> soup.find("meta", {"name":"City"})['content']
'Austin'
```

Comment: how can I do this if i want to find all instances, i.e. right now, soup.find("meta", {"name":"City"})['content'] gives the first result, but say there were another line in the soup that was <META NAME='City" content = "San Francisco">. how could I modify the code so that I'd get 'Austin' and 'San Francisco'?

Comment: Old question, but here's a simple solution in case anyone else comes looking for it: `soup.findAll("meta", {"name":"City"})['content']`. This will return all occurrences.

Comment: how can i get value of a specific attribute? means i have only attribute...

Comment: What is that `u` in `u'Austin`?

Comment: @mLstudent33 Python2 legacy stuff. Py3 uses `b""` for bytes and `""` for strings, but py2 used `""` for bytes and `u""` for strings (for "unicode")

Answer (score 34):

*theharshest* answered the question but here is another way to do the same thing.
Also, In your example you have NAME in caps and in your code you have name in lowercase.

```
s = '<div class="question" id="get attrs" name="python" x="something">Hello World</div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(s)

attributes_dictionary = soup.find('div').attrs
print attributes_dictionary
# prints: {'id': 'get attrs', 'x': 'something', 'class': ['question'], 'name': 'python'}

print attributes_dictionary['class'][0]
# prints: question

print soup.find('div').get_text()
# prints: Hello World
```

Comment: The mismatch in case is probably intentional because BeautifulSoup converts tags to lowercase by default. In this case:

BeautifulSoup('<META NAME="City" content="Austin">')  returns <meta content="Austin" name="City"/>

Answer (score 12):

6 years late to the party but I've been searching for how to extract an **html element's tag** *attribute value*, so for:

```
<span property="addressLocality">Ayr</span>
```

I want "addressLocality". I kept being directed back here, but the answers didn't really solve my problem.

How I managed to do it eventually:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

>>> soup = bs('<span property="addressLocality">Ayr</span>', 'html.parser')
>>> my_attributes = soup.find().attrs
>>> my_attributes
{u'property': u'addressLocality'}
```

As it's a dict, you can then also use `keys` and 'values'

```
>>> my_attributes.keys()
[u'property']
>>> my_attributes.values()
[u'addressLocality']
```

Hopefully it helps someone else!

Answer (score 9):

theharshest's answer is the best solution, but FYI the problem you were encountering has to do with the fact that a Tag object in Beautiful Soup acts like a Python dictionary. If you access tag['name'] on a tag that doesn't have a 'name' attribute, you'll get a KeyError.

Answer (score 8):

The following works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<META NAME="City" content="Austin">', 'html.parser')

metas = soup.find_all("meta")

for meta in metas:
    print meta.attrs['content'], meta.attrs['name']
```

Answer (score 1):

One can also try this solution :

To find the value, which is written in span of table

**htmlContent**

---

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            ID
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td>
            <span name="spanId" class="spanclass">ID123</span>
        </td>

        <td>
            <span>Bonny</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Python code**

---

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent, "lxml")
soup.prettify()

tables = soup.find_all("table")

for table in tables:
   storeValueRows = table.find_all("tr")
   thValue = storeValueRows[0].find_all("th")[0].string

   if (thValue == "ID"): # with this condition I am verifying that this html is correct, that I wanted.
      value = storeValueRows[1].find_all("span")[0].string
      value = value.strip()

      # storeValueRows[1] will represent <tr> tag of table located at first index and find_all("span")[0] will give me <span> tag and '.string' will give me value

      # value.strip() - will remove space from start and end of the string.

     # find using attribute :

     value = storeValueRows[1].find("span", {"name":"spanId"})['class']
     print value
     # this will print spanclass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If tdd='<td class="abc"> 75</td>'
In Beautifulsoup 

if(tdd.has_attr('class')):
   print(tdd.attrs['class'][0])


Result:  abc
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.