# How can I find this value?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to get value from this HTML

I've tried a lot of times but not working

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="2d7mJobmyIthzYDr">

    account_get = s.get('https://www.endclothing.com/gb/customer/account/login/#',headers=headers)
    soup = bs4.beautifulSoup(account_get.text, 'html.parser')
    form_key = soup.find('input',{'name':'form_key'})
```

I need to find value, thank you

UPDATE: the value changes everytime...

Comment: `form_key['value']` https://stackoverflow.com/a/11205758/6560549

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: That means `soup.find()` is returning `None`, meaning it’s not locating the input element with the parameters passed to the method..

Answer (score 0):

Once you find/isolate your element, you can get the value:

```
import bs4


html = '<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="2d7mJobmyIthzYDr">'


soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


value = soup.find('input')['value']
```

**Output:**

```
print (value)
2d7mJobmyIthzYDr
```