# How can I extract just the attribute "title" out of this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a little new to Python, and I am trying to understand how to extract the `'title='` attribute from this code (below).  I have been trying to use beautifulsoup for it but honestly anything that will work is good for me.

```html
<a class="image-link" href="/new-jersey/communities/holiday-city-at-berkeley" title="Holiday City at Berkeley"><div class="lazyload pulse out exited" style="height:auto"><div class="placeholder"><svg class="svg-placeholder-component" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 400 225" width="100%"><use xlink:href="#lazyload-placeholder"></use></svg></div></div></a>
```

I have tried `all[0].find_all('a', "title")` and `all[0].find_all("title")`, with both returning `'[]'`.

```html
<a class="image-link" href="/new-jersey/communities/holiday-city-at-berkeley" title="Holiday City at Berkeley"><div class="lazyload pulse out exited" style="height:auto"><div class="placeholder"><svg class="svg-placeholder-component" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 400 225" width="100%"><use xlink:href="#lazyload-placeholder"></use></svg></div></div></a>
```

Comment: please share your code. What is _all_ for example? You can use [edit] to add your code. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205386/python-beautifulsoup-get-an-attribute-value-based-on-the-name-attribute/11205758 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup , https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/  Note you can use select instead of find (which seems to be the most commonly returned search result )  Those links detail how to find and extract a title attribute. Emphasis _attribute_

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS selector to extract desired elements:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<a class="image-link" href="/new-jersey/communities/holiday-city-at-berkeley" title="Holiday City at Berkeley"><div class="lazyload pulse out exited" style="height:auto"><div class="placeholder"><svg class="svg-placeholder-component" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 400 225" width="100%"><use xlink:href="#lazyload-placeholder"></use></svg></div></div></a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for a in soup.select('a[title]'):
    print(a['title'])
```

Prints:

```
Holiday City at Berkeley
```