# How do I get a specific string from a string between two specified pieces of information

Tags: python, regex

I apologize for the confusing title. I looked around and I know how to get a string between two specified characters, but I am unsure on how to get a string between a phrase and character, such as `src="the information i want"`. In this case I want my starting point to be `src="`, and endpoint to be the first `"` after the start point. How would I go about specifying these parameters in the get method?

Below is the output of what I am asking for help with. Rather than have to manually copy and paste the second URL, I want to assign that string to a variable to automate the process.

```
>>> %Run myProject.py
enter URL
https://www.instagram.com/p/CAYGHWFFp-x/
<video class="tWeCl" playsinline="" poster="https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/100101005_584997515466659_2719890114744519125_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=111&_nc_ohc=DI3B3wg_vaQAX_MvEcQ&oh=06b611ef41299d4f0278467fb1d74e94&oe=5EC66079" 
preload="none" src="https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t50.2886-16/98205256_176119867089312_5443572653160790508_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=100&_nc_ohc=JtZXc2HiQ9kAX_097NE&oe=5EC68ACC&oh=ac92032cb89fa1dfbcb5f2fa9016c9ba" type="video/mp4"></video>
enter the URL
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why not just use a parser? Looks like html so you could use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: @CoryKramer I am using Beautiful Soup to get that video class. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out using the documentation or tutorials how to get any more specific than the video class.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205386/python-beautifulsoup-get-an-attribute-value-based-on-the-name-attribute/11205758

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse this content. Then you can look for `video` elements, and read their `src` attribute.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
for video in soup.find_all('video'):
    print(video.get('src'))
```

Output

```
https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t50.2886-1698205256_176119867089312_5443572653160790508_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=100&_nc_ohc=JtZXc2HiQ9kAX_097NE&oe=5EC68ACC&oh=ac92032cb89fa1dfbcb5f2fa9016c9ba
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't make the connection that I could use a for loop to do this.