# Is there a way to get a value usuing beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to add all the values from html table into the list. Figured out the way to do it here using
soup.find_all('a'), it gives me CSCI 101

```
<td><font size="-1" face="Verdana" color="#000080"><a href="javascript:my_win('202120CSCI101')">CSCI 101</a></font></td>
```

Now I need to do same thing here. Need to get the number 22481, but I couldn't find the way to do so.

```
<input type="hidden" name="sel_term" value="202120">
<input type="hidden" name="del_crn" value="00000">
<input type="hidden" name="save_crn" value="">
<td><input type="submit" name="sel_crn" value="22481" style="background-color:transparent;cursor:hand;border:none;color:#8A2BE2"></td>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: BeautifulSoup - get an attribute value based on the name attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205386/python-beautifulsoup-get-an-attribute-value-based-on-the-name-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

```
soup.find('input', {'type': 'submit'})['value']
```